# Finding singularities and calculating the residue

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

**Question** Find and classify the singularities and then calculate the residue for the following function: $$f(z) = \frac{(\cos(z)-1)(sin(z))}{e^{3z}z^4(z-\pi)^2}$$

**My Attempt:**

The singularities are $z= 0 \ \text{and} \ z=\pi$.

$z=0$ is a pole of order 1 because $(\cos(z)-1)(sin(z)$ has a zero of order 3 and $e^{3z}z^4(z-\pi)^2$ has a pole of order 4

$z=\pi$ is a pole of order 1 by the same deduction.

My problem is with calculating the residues. It seems I can't use the standard formula because the limit either doesn't exist or I am required to work out the derivative of $f(z)$ which looks nasty.

Comment: First off, $\cos(z)-1$ goes to zero as $z$ does, therefore the pole at $z=0$ has a pole with order less than 3.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? The derivative of $(\cos(z) - 1)(\sin(z))$ at z=0 is non-zero therefore the pole must be 3?

Comment: Try checking your derivatives again. I get that the numerator has a zero of order 3 at $z=0$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Even still, how would I work out the residue for $z=\pi$?

Comment: The numerator has a simple zero at $z=\pi$. So the function ends up having a simple pole at $z=\pi$ also, whereas above you concluded it was of order $2$. Can you compute the residue knowing that the pole is only of order $1$?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edit it. And no I can't because the limit doesn't exist because there remains a $z^3$ and a $(z-\pi)$ respectively in the denominator. What do I do about that?

Comment: Check out my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, we conclude that $f(z)$ has simple poles at $z=0$ and $z=\pi$. We will now compute the residue at $z=\pi$.

$$res_{\pi}f(z) = \lim_{z \to \pi} \frac{(\cos{z}-1)\sin{z}}{e^{3z}z^4(z-\pi)} $$

Note by L'Hôpital's rule that

$$ \lim_{z \to \pi} \frac{\sin{z}}{z-\pi}= \lim_{z \to \pi} \frac{\cos{z}}{1} = -1$$

And since clearly the limit of the remaining part of $f(z)$ exists we can split up the limit and say

$$ res_{\pi}f(z) = \left[ \lim_{z \to \pi} \frac{\sin{z}}{z-\pi} \right] \cdot 
   \left[ \lim_{z \to \pi} \frac{\cos{z}-1}{e^{3z}z^4}  \right]= \frac{2}   {e^{3\pi}\pi^4}  $$

The residue at $z=0$ can be calculated in a similar manner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!